# Is it possible to run (and possibly debug) Jupyter notebooks under Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jupyter-notebook, pydev

I am already using Eclipse with PyDev and am very satisfied with it.

I am looking for a way to run and maybe debug `.ipynb` files directly from Eclipse.

Is there currently any way to do this? I looked up similar questions on stackoverflow but didn't find a clear answer developing possible options (if any).

Comment: ["IPYNB notebooks are plain text files formatted using JSON, making them human-readable..."](https://fileinfo.com/extension/ipynb)  Yes, you can edit JSON in Eclipse.  There are probably better tools for editing IPYNB files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can run it from the command line, you should be able to create an external tool launch configuration to run it (using the menu `Run` > `External Tools`).

For debugging Python code from a notebook you can use the remote debugger (https://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html) -- i.e.: something as importing `pydevd` and calling `pydevd.settrace()` from the notebook.

Besides that, I'm not aware of any special integration for editing `ipynb` files in Eclipse.

Comment: Any plans to integrate this into PyDev (VS code does it)?

Comment: Unfortunately no, there aren't plans to do a special integration for ipynb files in Eclipse/PyDev.

Comment: This is a pity, because PyDev is a great tool and I really mean it

Comment: Thanks for the compliments ;)  -- unfortunately, supporting `ipynb` would be a pretty big undertaking and I'm not sure having yet another way to interpret such files would be worth it (in general, you can open those files with a jupyter server and just open it in a browser -- it could actually be opened inside a browser window in Eclipse in that case -- vscode does have a nice integration, but for PyDev, I feel like it's more worthy of my time to improve on pure Python than doing an integration for notebooks given the time it'd take to do such an integration).